# How to change the HBase base dir in HbaseTestingUtility

Tags: windows, scala, intellij-idea, hbase, hbasetestingutility

I am having issues running the HbaseTestingUtility within IntelliJ IDE, and I can see the following error is probably a result of the file name being too long:

```
16/03/14 22:45:13 WARN datanode.DataNode: IOException in BlockReceiver.run(): 
java.io.IOException: Failed to move meta file for ReplicaBeingWritten, blk_1073741825_1001, RBW
getNumBytes()     = 7
getBytesOnDisk()  = 7
getVisibleLength()= 7
getVolume()       = C:\Users\user1\Documents\work\Repos\hadoop-analys\reporting\mrkts-surveillance\target\test-data\9654a646-e923-488a-9e20-46396fd15292\dfscluster_6b264e6b-0218-4f30-ad5b-72e838940b1e\dfs\data\data1\current
getBlockFile()    = C:\Users\user1\Documents\work\Repos\hadoop-analys\reporting\mrkts-surveillance\target\test-data\9654a646-e923-488a-9e20-46396fd15292\dfscluster_6b264e6b-0218-4f30-ad5b-72e838940b1e\dfs\data\data1\current\BP-429386217-192.168.1.110-1457991908038\current\rbw\blk_1073741825
bytesAcked=7
bytesOnDisk=7 from C:\Users\user1\Documents\work\Repos\hadoop-analys\reporting\mrkts-surveillance\target\test-data\9654a646-e923-488a-9e20-46396fd15292\dfscluster_6b264e6b-0218-4f30-ad5b-72e838940b1e\dfs\data\data1\current\BP-429386217-192.168.1.110-1457991908038\current\rbw\blk_1073741825_1001.meta to    C:\Users\user1\Documents\work\Repos\hadoop-analys\reporting\mrkts-surveillance\target\test-data\9654a646-e923-488a-9e20-46396fd15292\dfscluster_6b264e6b-0218-4f30-ad5b-72e838940b1e\dfs\data\data1\current\BP-429386217-192.168.1.110-1457991908038\current\finalized\subdir0\subdir0\blk_1073741825_1001.meta
   at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.moveBlockFiles(FsDatasetImpl.java:615)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.BlockPoolSlice.addBlock(BlockPoolSlice.java:250)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsVolumeImpl.addBlock(FsVolumeImpl.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.finalizeReplica(FsDatasetImpl.java:1119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.finalizeBlock(FsDatasetImpl.java:1100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver$PacketResponder.finalizeBlock(BlockReceiver.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver$PacketResponder.run(BlockReceiver.java:1233)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 3: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any idea, how I can specify the base directory of Hbasetestingutility to not use this gargantuan starting directory?

Thanks,

Comment: Basically you need to do something like : 
`System.setProperty("test.build.data.basedirectory", "c:/HBase/");`

Comment: @Stanislav suggestion solved this issue at my end too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use test.build.data.basedirectory.

Please take a look at **getDataTestDir** in [HBaseCommonTestingUtility](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseCommonTestingUtility.java)

```
/**
 * System property key to get base test directory value
 */
public static final String BASE_TEST_DIRECTORY_KEY =
  "test.build.data.basedirectory";

/**
  * @return Where to write test data on local filesystem, specific to
  * the test.  Useful for tests that do not use a cluster.
  * Creates it if it does not exist already.
  */
public Path getDataTestDir() {
   if (this.dataTestDir == null) {
     setupDataTestDir();
   }
   return new Path(this.dataTestDir.getAbsolutePath());
 }
```